# how should I solve the problem of XMLHttpresponse

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have written some of code following :

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
  a.open("POST", "third.php", false);
  a.responseType = "";
  var type = a.response;
  a.send(null);
  document.getElementById("response1").innerHTML = a.response;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!-- This is HTML div -->
<div id="response2" style="background-color:#6FF;">
</div>
```

but it returns null value. please Anyone said what is the reason of it?

Comment: The DIV ID is `response2`, but you're assigning to `response1`.

Comment: Is there any error in the JavaScript console?

Comment: But later I have asign the DIV ID as response1

Comment: It shows blank...

Comment: Use the Network tab to see what response is being returned from `third.php`. Is it returning anything?

Comment: Yes it shows the time.... But when ever I type the code without VAR type and just written a.response It runs...

Comment: You should get out of the habit of using synchronous XMLHttpRequest. Try doing it the right way with an `readystatechange` event listener.